# ICS VpnService pop up dialog

Tags: popup, vpn, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to write a VPN app using VpnService. I started my app based on the sample ToyVpn. It seems to work fine but I am wondering if there is a way to get rid of the pop up dialog when I click connect. I am hoping that I could just click "connect" and it would start without having to click the "I trust this application..." check box and "Ok".

Thanks.

Comment: U had mentioned ToyVpn is working.. Plz share ur codebase or any doc of how made it work. bcoz its not working for me.

Comment: did you ever find a work around to the popup?  I'm in the same position and am trying to figure out a solution too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.  They seem to be very careful about this class.  If you take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) you can see it says:

Letting applications intercept packets raises huge security concerns. A VPN application can easily break the network. Besides, two of them may conflict with each other. The system takes several actions to address these issues. Here are some key points:

- ***User action is required to create a VPN connection***. [emphasis mine]
- There can be only one VPN connection running at the same time. The existing interface is deactivated when a new one is created.
- A system-managed notification is shown during the lifetime of a VPN connection.
- A system-managed dialog gives the information of the current VPN connection. It also provides a button to disconnect.
  The network is restored automatically when the file descriptor is closed. It also covers the cases when a VPN application is crashed or killed by the system.

Since it says that user action is required to create the VPN connection, I assume they mean this is something you cannot control yourself.

Comment: what would be required to be changed in the OS to prevent the popup from happening, about?  Is is something that could possibly be done, if I have root?

Comment: I don't see how root would change the behaviour.  If the API itself is the one popping up the popup, the user running the app that calls the API shouldn't matter.  Of course this is my speculation and I could be wrong.

Comment: but using root, could there be a way to suppress the message perhaps.  For example, I was wondering I could programatically move the cursor and then click the proper buttons to hide the box.  This might not be possible with normal access but using root might make it possible.  Do you think such a thing might work?

Comment: I haven't done much with respect to rooting a device to get around these things.  I can tell you that if you have a rooted device doing something with 'su', the user will get a different popup saying that the application is requesting root permissions before it is able to actually do anything.  So either way, I think the user would be getting a popup.  In this case, I would think it's better to say "Can I have VPN permission for my VPN s/w?" instead of "Can I have permission to do anything I want on your phone?"